# PolynomialFeatures LinearRegression ValueError: shapes not aligned

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write a function which trains and tests a LinearRegression with PolynomialFeatures. Here is my code:

```
def get_lr2(pdeg):
  from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
  from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
  from sklearn.metrics.regression import r2_score
  from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
  import numpy as np
  import pandas as pd

  np.random.seed(0)
  n = 15
  x = np.linspace(0,10,n) + np.random.randn(n)/5
  y = np.sin(x)+x/6 + np.random.randn(n)/10
  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=0)
  test_data = np.linspace(0,10,100).reshape(100,1)
  X_trainT     = X_train.reshape(-1,1)
  y_trainT     = y_train.reshape(-1,1)
  poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=pdeg)
  X_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_trainT)
  X_train1, X_test1, y_train1, y_test1 = train_test_split(X_poly, y_trainT, random_state = 0)
  linreg1 = LinearRegression().fit(X_train1, y_train1)
  return linreg1.predict(test_data)
```

When I call the function (get_lr2(1)) I am getting

```
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
  ---> 84 get_lr2(1)

  <ipython-input-29-a9966181155e> in get_lr2(pdeg)
  23     X_train1, X_test1, y_train1, y_test1 = train_test_split(X_poly, y_trainT, random_state = 0)
  24     linreg1 = LinearRegression().fit(X_train1, y_train1)
  ---> 25     return linreg1.predict(test_data)

  ValueError: shapes (100,1) and (2,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

Can you help?

Comment: The shape (x,y dimensions) of your test and train data appear to not be the same. Can you check if 'test_data' and 'X_train1' have the same shape in your function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is rather strange. Let's try to reformat it in several ways:

- Train_test _split.

  You doing `train_test_split` and then throw away your test set and create another one. This is rather strange. If you want that your train test splits sizes were in proportion 15/100 come from, just set this in train_test_split option. So test size should be `100/(100+15) ~= 0.87`.
- Preprocessing.

  If you want to apply some preprocessing(polynomial features here) transformers you can apply them to whole dataset, not some split. This is not true if  transformer is dependent to data(in that case you must do `fit_transform` on train set and then 
  only `transform` on test set) but in your case it does not matter.
- Reshape.

  After  our improvements you should do reshape only in one place - while initializing x. Scikit learn models expect your X data to be matrix or column-vector(if only one feature presented). So `reshape(-1,1)` here will turn you row-vector to column-vector.

So the code will look like this:

```
def get_lr2(pdeg):
    np.random.seed(0)
    n = 115
    x = (np.linspace(0,10,n) + np.random.randn(n)/5).reshape(-1,1)
    y = np.sin(x)+x/6 + np.random.randn(n)/10

    X_poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=pdeg).fit_transform(x)

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_poly, y, random_state=0, test_size=0.87)

    linreg1 = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
    return linreg1.predict(X_test)

get_lr2(2)
```