# Shapes not aligned when fitting polynomial regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

Long time listener, first time caller...

I know a similar question has been answered in the past (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408006/polynomialfeatures-linearregression-valueerror-shapes-not-aligned) for other thread I have referenced), but I am still having difficulties.  How can I get my regression to fit?  My code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

#data
np.random.seed(0)
n = 15
x = np.linspace(0,10,n) + np.random.randn(n)/5
y = np.sin(x)+x/6 + np.random.randn(n)/10

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=0)

#regression fitting
X_predict_input = np.linspace(0,10,100).reshape(-1,1)
y_train = y_train.reshape((-1,1))
X_train = X_train.reshape((-1,1))

#looping through different degree values
for i, degree in enumerate([1,3,6,9]):
    poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=degree)
    X_train_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_train)
    linreg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train_poly, y_train)
    result[i,:] = linreg.predict(X_predict_input)
```

I tried to fix the shaping issues with X_train and y_train, but after looking into each shape, I am thinking that the X_train_poly is what is driving this error...

```
X_train shape: (11, 1)
y_train shape: (11, 1)
X_train_poly shape: (11, 10)
```

Respective error message:

> ValueError: shapes (100,1) and (2,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)

When I try to address the shape inconsistencies in X_train_poly by the following...

```
X_train_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_train).reshape((-1,1))
```

...I receive this error:

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [22, 11]

I have spent an embarrassing amount of time on this, so any insight at all would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I get a different error message when I run your script: `ValueError: X has 1 features, but LinearRegression is expecting 2 features as input.`.  This error makes sense, since with `degree=1` the regression has 2 features, yet `X_predict_input ` only has one. I don't know how you got the ValueError you show in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is quite simple.  You're using the `PolynomialFeatures` transform to generate features for the training data but when it comes to prediction, you're not applying the same transform to the input data.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

# data
np.random.seed(0)
n = 15
x = np.linspace(0, 10, n) + np.random.randn(n)/5
y = np.sin(x) + x/6 + np.random.randn(n)/10

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x.reshape((-1, 1)), 
                                                    y.reshape((-1, 1)), 
                                                    random_state=0)

# Check data matrices are in columns
assert(X_train.shape == (11, 1))
assert(y_train.shape == (11, 1))

# Build library of polynomial features
degree = 3
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree)
X_train_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_train)
assert(X_train_poly.shape == (11, 4))

# Fit model
linreg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train_poly, y_train)

# Make prediction
X_predict = np.linspace(0, 10, 100).reshape(-1, 1)
X_predict_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_predict)
y_predict = linreg.predict(X_predict_poly)
assert(y_predict.shape == X_predict.shape)
```

**Update:**

To avoid the inconvenience of having to apply the transform every time you make a prediction, you might want to check out [sklearn.Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html):

```py
# Using a pipeline to automate the input transformation
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree)
model = LinearRegression()
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('t', poly), ('m', model)])

linreg = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predict2 = linreg.predict(X_predict)

assert(np.array_equal(y_predict, y_predict2))
```